# Ordenar los números de menor a mayor según su valor absoluto, pero retornar los valores con su signo original

Tags: javascript

Me piden esto:

> Recibes una lista de números. Debes ordenar los números de menor a mayor según su valor absoluto. Eso quiere decir que los números negativos pierden el signo y se ordenan como si fueran positivos.
> Por ejemplo, si recibes [5, -10, -2, -25, -7] deberías devolver [-2, 5, -7, -10, -25].
> Puedes usar el método Math.abs(num) para obtener el valor absoluto de un número.

```
function sortAbsoluteNumbers(numbers) {
  // tu código aquí
  }
```

---

Yo hice esto:

```
let numeros=[5, -10, -2, -25, -7];

function ordenAbs (array){
  let total=[]
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let nTotal=Math.abs(array[i]);
    console.log(nTotal)
    total.push(nTotal);
  }

  total.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
return total
}

console.log(ordenAbs(numeros))
```

pero al correrlo me devuelve los números del array positivos y los arregla bien, pero no debería traérmelos en positivo, y no sé hacerlo.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask]. Fijate qué diferente se lee tu pregunta cuando se especifica claramente cuál es el problema/enunciado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa la propia funcion que pasas como argumento a *sort()* para convertir los argumentos **a** y **b** a sus valores absolutos, y usas esos valores para la comparación, esto no te afectara los signos del arreglo ordenado:

```
let array = [5, -10, -2, -25, -7] 

function sortAbsoluteNumbers(arr) {
  return [...arr].sort((a, b) => {
    if(Math.abs(a) < Math.abs(b)) return -1
    if(Math.abs(a) > Math.abs(b)) return 1
  })
}

console.log(sortAbsoluteNumbers(array))
```

Puedes leer la documentación de [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) para entender un poco como funciona, y porque decidí devolver 1 en un caso y -1 en el otro.

Comment: El [operador `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) permite *expandir* un iterable. En este caso permite crear una copia del arreglo, preservando el original. También me parece buena idea dejar un link a la documentación de [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: @Mateo olvidé mencionarlo al autor de la pregunta, gracias

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! @infinit3Loop__ a todos :)

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ te falta `return 0` para el caso que sean iguales. Hoy funciona, pero puede que dentro de unos años de error.